# Load CSS element on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a "loading" element that I want to display when a user clicks a button. See the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCJdA/2/).

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to have this CSS animation load when a user clicks a button. I've tried to delay the CSS from loading but that does not accomplish what I'm after. How do I change my code to make it load the animation on click?

```css
body { min-height: 100%; background: tomato }
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.9em;
  color: beige;
  font: 800 900% Baskerville, 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, serif;
}
h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: attr(data-content);
  color:#34495e;
  max-width: 4em;
  -webkit-animation: loading 5s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  0% {
    max-width : 0
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 data-content="Loading Results">Loading Results</h1>
```

Comment: you can simply add the animation in a css class and apply that class on you element on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below, but also check out my 5 mins intro to CSS animation http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/web-design/css/5-min-css-animation-beginner-tutorial/

```js
var loadButton = document.getElementById("load");
var title = document.getElementById("title");
loadButton.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  title.classList.toggle("loading");  
})
```

```css
body { min-height: 100%; background: tomato }
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.9em;
    color: beige;
    font: 800 900% Baskerville, 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, serif;
}
h1:before {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    content: attr(data-content);
    color:#34495e;
    max-width: 4em;
}

.loading:before{
  -webkit-animation: loading 5s linear;  
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
    0% {
        max-width : 0
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="load">start loading</button>
<h1 id="title" data-content="Loading Results">Loading Results</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this

```js
function addClass(){
document.getElementById("head").className = "load";
}
```

```css
body { min-height: 100%; background: tomato }
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.9em;
    color: beige;
    font: 800 900% Baskerville, 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, serif;
}
.load {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    content: attr(data-content);
    color:#34495e;
    max-width: 4em;
    -webkit-animation: loading 5s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
    0% {
        max-width : 0
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="head" data-content="Loading Results">Loading Results</h1>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="addClass()">
```